# Application to handle form approval

Tags: php, asp.net

Hopefully this is the right place for this question.

I have done a fair amount of research and yet to find anything that matches what I want. What I'm envisioning is the following. Let me know if any of you know of a program that will do what I want.
Also it must be web-based
anom user -> fills out form ->
email gets sent to admin saying xyz has filled out form abc with links to approve/disapprove request.

admin can also login and edit form and resent results to original submitter. Also once the admin approves/disapproves request the original submitter gets an approve/disapprove email.

and you can search by date submitted, specific project/form, status of request(submitted, approved, disapproved).

any ideas all on where I could find this? I started to look into drupal with workflows and actions but it just doesn't flow right for this

Comment: Try asking at http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: My guess would be that you won't find any "out of the box" solution that will accomodate this.  It is something that can be programmed in any number of languages.  .NET Workflow would be an ideal candidate for such a solution.  But you're probably going to have to have someone code something like this for you.

Comment: @ChrisF - Since his tags state php and asp.net, I assumed he had SOME knowledge. Besides, programmers active there might know more about ongoing projects that could facilitate Chris' needs. I didn't tried to tell him that his question doesn't belong here, merely another place where he could ask, increasing the odds of finding something useful.

Comment: Well both of you are correct.  I posted it on superuser.com since I am looking for a software solution.  And yes I am a programmer.  So Can someone transfer it out to stackoverflow?

Thanks

Comment: That is a very specific solution you are looking for, and not a very complicated one I think, so believe coding it your self would be the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you need to program the solution yourself, using something like PHP or ASP.NET (as you specified) as possible technologies, and a backend database like MySQL. If your process takes more than one sentence to describe, the exact system you want usually does not yet exist.

If you don't have the knowledge to code this, it sounds like you will need to hire someone who does. This isn't exactly a specific "how do I do this" programming question; this is a specification for an application, which a competent programmer should be able to turn into a working application for you.

Best of luck!

Comment: Actually I think I'm just going to use drupal with the following modules.
actions,triggers,workflow

thanks for all the comments guys.